help with courses and planning
I am senior in hs about to go to an r1 public (not top or anything) uni next year. I planned on majoring in math and econ, with the goal of getting a PhD in applied math (hopefully stochastic processes or pdes). I have some questions to be able to improve my cv:

Is it better to graduate earlier or wait and pass some more related courses to my major?

Is it necessary I have proven skills about research in my CV (I am a bachelor student)? If so, How can I get to that?

How can I improve my chance of getting a good internship?

If I want to select between to: 1. continue my major or 2. change it to a more applied one, which critria I should consider to have an appropriate selection?



What country do you want to study in?

Welcome to Academia.SE. I recommend that you [edit] your post to make it clearer what it is you want to know. We can't really offer individual career counseling (so we don't need your list of classes), but we can maybe help if you boil it down to a well-defined question. Perhaps something like: "will my PhD application in economics in the US be competitive if I do many internships and graduate-level classes as an undergraduate, or would it be better to graduate early and do a master's degree?" Please see our [help] to learn more

I think this is an important question. I would vote for reopening if I knew how to do it. If we don't go into the details of the question, but have a look at it from a general perspective, it reveals that sharmbe117 is trying to plan his life and can't do it due to lack of knowledge of the possible paths. This is a very common situation among young students and very rarely addressed. sharmbe117 is doing the right thing asking it here. We are doing the wrong thing not helping him out.

I approved your edit, but now you have multiple questions. SE guidelines enforce users to ask one question at time. Please edit your post again or it's unlikely to be reopened.
